# New to React - I don't understand why these values are undefined. How should I be accessing these values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am new to React and could do with some help understanding where I am going wrong here. I am making a fetch request to an API and setting the response to the "events" array with setState. The fetch request is working and if I use the following code I am able to render the correct information for each element in the events array:

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const fetchEvents = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/events");
      const parsed = await response.json();
      setEvents(parsed);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
      {events.map((event) => (
        <li className="events" key={event._id}>
          <Text>{event.title}</Text>
          <Text>{event.location}</Text>
          <Text>{event.date}</Text>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

However, what I would LIKE to be able to do is access specific indexes in the array in order to render specific information rather than the same information for each element. for example:

```
  return (
    <>
        <p>{events[1].title}</p>
        <p>{events[0].location}</p>
        <p>{events[2].description}</p>

    </>
  )}
```

This works sometimes but whenever refresh the above values revert to being undefined. I am assuming this has something to do with the events being reset to an empty array at the beginning of my function?

What is the best way for me to achieve what I am trying to please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `useState([]);` Your initial state is an empty array, so any value you get out of it is going to be `undefined`. What would you like to display during the time where the array is empty (ie, while the data is loading)? Also, what should happen if the data you get is less than 3 events?

Comment: You're most likely getting an error because `[][1]`,`[][0]`, and `[][2]` don't exist. These don't exist because you need to wait for your `fetch` response to return. The reason the original method doesn't fail is because `[].map` just iterates through nothing.  You could fix this to not render anything until `events` is populated

Comment: Hi @NicholasTower thank you that was the missing piece. I added a variable for Loading, initialised as true and then only render the above if Loading is false, which I set as part of the fetchEvents function. Worked like a charm. I knew I was missing something obvious but you nailed it thank you.